# 1 x 2 brick with square hole on top identification

Tags: part-identification

Hoping somebody can help identify this part. It's a 1 x 2 brick, but has a square hole on one side.  Many a part has got me stuck, but rebrickable has helped me many times.   Can't seem to find this one.

[image]

Comment: I've never seen a brick like this, very interesting! I am wondering if it might be a non-production prototype piece.  The bricks' profile looks exactly like brick# 989, but missing the "finger top" of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like @JohnnyB commented, this is the lower part of [76385 Hinge Brick 1 x 2 Locking with Single Finger On Top](https://rebrickable.com/parts/76385/hinge-brick-1-x-2-locking-with-single-finger-on-top/): [image]

Comment: That's exactly what I commented already, 989 is one of the alternate part numbers.  I didn't see any evidence in the photo that it had been forced apart, and the scratches on the exposed surface suggest it's been this way for a long time.  What is your guess on how it came to be?

Comment: Either a manufacturing error, or breakage after purchase. The first is more probable though, as I imagine any force strong enough to break the "finger" would damage the base as well.

Comment: @JohnnyB I'm terribly sorry for this misunderstanding. I researched and wrote my answer without reading your comment and later on was in a hurry so did not consider upvoting the comment. I'll try to rectify this as far as I can.

Comment: is there a specific reason this is made out two parts?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe since the assembly of sub-parts is a complex and expensive operation, I assume the alternative was considered to be even more complex and expensive. A probable reason is the complexity of the mould halves, of which the side including the "finger" would have to have two moving sub-parts for forming the circular cavities on the sides. Forming the finger sub-part as a separate unit allows both sub-parts to be moulded by a simple two-part mould without any moving components. If it's still not clear, please ask a new question, so that pictures can be added to explain the process.

Comment: @zovits I think I understand, the "finger" piece is molded "sideways" while the brick is molded "upright" and then they're combined?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe exactly, that's what I suspect. Note however, that I don't work for Lego, have no relevant experience in injection moulding, and can only speculate based on what I have read and watched about the topic.

Comment: @zovits you think it would be a good question for this site to ask what you suggested initially? or did the topic more or less exhaust itself in the comments here?

Comment: @htmlcoderexe There is not much more that could be said about the topic, but as a top level Q&A it would be better manageable than a comment stream. IMO the question itself would be on topic, as we explicitly do allow questions about "The history of The LEGO Group or elements", even if such manufacturing practices and decisions are impossible to know with certainty for anyone not working for TLG and probably non-disclosable for anyone who does.

Answer (score 3):

Well, between my comment and zovits "seconding" the idea, I think it's safe to assume we've established what this part "was".  I did a lot of searching earlier online, looking through people's collections of non-production and prototype rare parts and couldn't find this "version" of the part.  So, whatever the story of how it came to be, I would certainly consider this to be a rare keepsake.  Here is a photo of the inside of these bricks with the square insert from the "finger" easily identifiable.

[image]

I couldn't bring myself to attempt a disassembly since I apparently don't have many of these and they aren't the more common color of Black and Dark Gray.  Perhaps Rin Rio-Oki will happen upon this question and take the initiative of dissecting one?  Fingers crossed ;)